# Access a field from a function call without an intermediate variable

Tags: powershell

Say I have the following powershell code:

```
function GetImageInfo()
{
    [OutputType([ImageInfo])]

    [ImageInfo] $imageInfo = [ImageInfo]::new()
    $imageInfo.Owner = "Me"
    $imageInfo.PrimaryTechnology = "jpeg"
    $imageInfo.OperatingSystem = "Windows"
    $imageInfo.OperatingSystemVersion = "10"    

    return $imageInfo   
}

class ImageInfo
{
    [string] $Owner
    [string] $PrimaryTechnology
    [string] $OperatingSystem
    [string] $OperatingSystemVersion
    [string[]] $OptionalQualifiers
}
```

I now want to call `GetImageInfo` and put the value of `Owner` in a variable.

I can do it like this:

```
$info = GetImageInfo
$owner = $imageInfo.Owner
```

But I was surprised that this does not work:

```
# Throws an error
$owner = GetImageInfo.Owner
```

For what I am doing now the shorter option would be nice.

**Is there a way to get a field directly from a method call in PowerShell?**

Comment: `(GetImageInfo).Owner`

Comment: @beatcracker - That was it!  Post as answer and I will accept. (And thank you!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap function call in the parenthesis. This [allows you to let output from a command participate in an expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-6#grouping-operator--):

```bsh
$owner = (GetImageInfo).Owner
```

Comment: Thanks again.  So simple, but this one stumped me for a while!